# Why can't Bouncycastle's PEMReader read this M2Crypto-generated PEM?

Tags: java, python, encryption, bouncycastle, m2crypto

I use the following Python code, using M2Crypto, to generate an RSA key pair in PEM format:

```
bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer()
key_pair = RSA.gen_key(1024, 65537)
key_pair.save_key_bio(bio, cipher=None)
return bio.read()
```

And the following Java code, using Bouncycastle, to try to read it:

```
String signPem = ...;
PEMReader pemReader = new PEMReader(new StringReader(signPem));
Object signingKey = pemReader.readObject();
```

The `signPem` string is the same as what `bio.read()` returned; no data that I can see is getting munged between the two programs; it's `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n` etc.

However, the readObject() call throws a ClassCastException:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERSequence
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Object.fromByteArray(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader.readKeyPair(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader.readObject(Unknown Source)
```

So obviously BC misidentifies the data in the PEM is not a key pair for some reason - but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a debugger to Bouncycastle, I have discovered the "cause", but it only puzzles me more; the cast is failing even though all types seem to be correct.

*[If A extends B extends C, why can I cast to A but get a ClassCastException casting to C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634487/if-a-extends-b-extends-c-why-can-i-cast-to-a-but-get-a-classcastexception-castin)*

Comment: The "why" is because PEMReader was importing Android's private BC implementation. This can be fixed by renaming your own BC, or targeting a more recent version of Android.